# Is Google Material Design Support RTL layout?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, google-material-icons

I'm trying to create HTML Page using Material Design grid system and implement the input fields view with all the nice features its offers in RTL Direction.
There is 2 Problems:
1. the grid layout not flliped to rtl
2. the input fields not working as expected

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/pooper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body dir="rtl">

<div class="row right">
    <div class="col s1">1</div>
    <div class="col s1">2</div>
    <div class="col s1">3</div>
    <div class="col s1">4</div>
    <div class="col s1">5</div>
    <div class="col s1">6</div>
    <div class="col s1">7</div>
    <div class="col s1">8</div>
    <div class="col s1">9</div>
    <div class="col s1">10</div>
    <div class="col s1">11</div>
    <div class="col s1">12</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col s10" style="border-style: solid;border-color:black;">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="col s12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 right">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix right">search</i>
                            <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                            <label for="icon_prefix2">search</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

i've tried all conventional ways like body and html dir and added right to as class name but nothing helped.